# Check if ahk (autohotkey) script is running

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I am working on an autohotkey script and I wanted to know if you can check if another script is currently running.

I found out that this is what you have to do to close a running script:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinClose, %pathToScript% ahk_class AutoHotkey
```

So I thought this is what you have to do to check if another script is running:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
IfWinActive, %pathToScript% ahk_class AutoHotkey
{
    //code to do when script is active
}
```

This is not working though.
Can you help me ?

Comment: The answer too this was not to use `ifWinActive` but `ifWinExist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ test this ]

1 - Create a random script that stays running, yet hidden, like this:

```
F::
Msgbox "running..." ; to test if it's ok or already closed.
```

2 - Now you create a script to test what you wanna do. My test can close hidden scripts by their names:

```
pathToScript = %A_ScriptDir%\teste.exe

DetectHiddenWindows, On
IfWinExist, %pathToScript%
{
    WinWait, %pathToScript%,
    IfWinNotActive, %pathToScript%, , WinActivate, %pathToScript%,
    WinWaitActive, %pathToScript%,

    WinClose, %pathToScript% ahk_class AutoHotkey
    MsgBox "OK"
}
```

Hope it may help you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this but something useful I have in my script is the

```
Reload
```

which recompiles and restarts the saved script file.  See:the [Reload document information](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Reload.htm)